# Does it make sense to use debounce for $scope.$apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen an approach to reduce number of `$digest` loops with debouncing of `$scope.$apply` method, something like:

```
$scope.$apply = _.debounce($scope.$apply, 250);
```

Does it make sense? What kind of problems can I come across with it?

Comment: It's just a tradeoff. *If you do debounce:* The UI won't be updated as often and there will potentially be a 250 ms delay between your app state being updated and the UI reflecting those changes. *If you don't debounce:* The UI may appear sluggish because there are too many digest cycles per second. (The real solution is to find a way to reduce the frequency and duration of digest cycles by reducing the number of bindings and watches in the app.)

Comment: @MatthewKing I've seen this only on my current project. From my perspective this approach leads to 250ms delay for every update on the UI, doesn't it break UX?

Comment: It depends. For many UXes, a 250ms delay does break UX. For others (updating stock chart, updating weather), the user may not notice or assume that the delay is due to business delay. I would say it's case by case.

Comment: @MatthewKing thanks for explanation. have you voted to close this question?

Comment: No, must be someone else I guess

Comment: @MatthewKing you can make your first comment as an answer, I'll accept it, if you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a tradeoff.

- *If you do debounce:* The UI won't be updated as often and there will potentially be a 250 ms delay between your app state being updated and the UI reflecting those changes.
- *If you don't debounce:* The UI may appear sluggish because there are too many digest cycles per second. (The real solution is to find a way to reduce the frequency and duration of digest cycles by reducing the number of bindings and watches in the app.)